# Contagem de comentarios // e /* */ em C

Tags: c, buffer

Estou tentando fazer um programinha em C que abra um arquivo `.txt`, `.c` ou qualquer outro em modo de leitura, para contar os comentários feitos com `//` ou `/* */`.

Estou fazendo da seguine maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//funcao de contagem de comentarios
void contalinha(FILE *pFile,int *coment1L, int *comentVL)
{
    char buff_linha[100];
    char atual, prox;
    int i;

    while (!feof(pFile))
    { //DO
         fgets(buff_linha, 100, pFile);
            puts(buff_linha);//PROVA QUE O BUFF ESTA FUNCIONANDO
         for(i=0; i<= 100; i++)//laco lendo o buff da linha
         {
             atual = buff_linha[i];
             prox = buff_linha[i+1];

             if(atual == '/' && prox == '/'){
                  *coment1L += 1;// comentarios de uma linha
             }
             else
                if(atual == '/' && prox == '*'){
                 *comentVL += 1;// comentarios de varias linhas
                }
        }

       }
    return;
}

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int n = 0;
    int coment1L = 0, comentVL = 0, flag = 0, flag2 = 0;
    FILE *pFile;

    system("cls");

    pFile = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    if (pFile !=NULL)
    {
        printf("Lendo arquivo...\n\n");
        contalinha(pFile,&coment1L, &comentVL);
        fclose(pFile);

        if(strcmp(argv[2], "-c") || strcmp(argv[2], "-comment")){
                printf("\n\t\t - Contagem de Comentarios - \n\n");
                printf("\n\tnumero de comentarios: %d", coment1L + comentVL);
                printf("\n\tNumero de comentarios com //: %d", coment1L);
                printf("\n\tNumero de comentarios com /*: %d", comentVL);
                printf("\n\n");
        }

    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Utilizarei ele para ler códigos `.c`. Estou lendo linha por linha do arquivo,
armazenando a linha em um vetor `buff[100]` e percorrendo esse vetor em busca do `//` ou `/*`. Até a parte de armazenar no `buff` está funcionando, mas me parece que não esta percorrendo o vetor procurando correspondências.

Comment: Olá, Luiz Claudio. Seja bem-vindo. Poderia explicar melhor quais são os sintomas? Como sabe que não está funcionando?

Comment: eu estou rodando e ele esta jogando numeros sem logica como resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola.

Recomendo que o senhor troque o fgets por fscanf;

```
int line_size = fscanf( pFile, "%s", &buff_linha);
for(int i = 0 ; i < line_size ; i++ )
{
   // realiza a contagem
}
```

Outra abordagem seria fazer a chamada do strlen

```
int line_size = strlen(buff_linha);
```

Muito provavelmente você está lendo lixo ao ler todo o vetor e não somente ler a string até o caracter '\0'.

Pense em uma linha curta com 3 palavras o que da 30 letras, o que o teu software vai contar até o caractere 100 ?!

Comment: Obrigado Israel!
troquei o fgets pelo fscanf e funcionou para o /* mas nao funcionou para o // mas obrigado brother (y)